# Testing the time it takes for your tests to run

Tags: c#, selenium, testing

I have a list of feature tests that use selenium to run. I was wondering if there was a way where you could test that it didn't take over a certain time for your tests to run.

E.g. Given I run my Selenium tests
Then they should not take over 45 seconds to execute

Here is an example of two tests being run in the same scenario:

```
[Given(@"I navigate to the CIE attributes page through ""(.*)""")]
    public void GivenINavigateToTheCIEAttributesPageThrough(string browserName)
    {
        ChooseBrowser(browserName);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:49350/CIE_Attributes");
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    [Then(@"I see the page is loaded")]
    public void ThenISeeThePageIsLoaded()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("ATTRIBUTES", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h1")).Text);
        Assert.AreEqual("Customer Insight Engine - CEA CIE Attributes", driver.Title);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to measure the total execution time for all of your tests, or just for one single test? (Given the specific duration you mention, I guess the former. 45 seconds for just one test would be quite a lot.)

Comment: I posted a answer in regards of Unit tests, deleted that. Sorry, I thought this was a question about unit tests.

Comment: I have a scenario which runs through lots of different steps. I want to measure the time taken for all to run. It is selenium so opens the browser to perform the checks. It takes longer than normal unit tests but I admit 45 is still quite long. Was just using it for an example